# How to use memcached from codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, memcached

How to use `memcached` from codeigniter, and how to store session data to `memcached`.
Please help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here is the link to my `memcached_library` for codeigniter

http://github.com/tomschlick/memcached-library

let me know what you think and if you have any issues please raise them in the issues section of the github repository

Comment: thanks alot about the library. I'm going to use memcached as main cache layer and use memcached to store session data. Have you ever use memcached to store session data?

Comment: no but i never thought of it. i dont think it would be too difficult to overload the session library to append add and delete to/from memcache before and after the queries that the session class normally uses. now that you mention this im going to tinker around at work doing this for our applications... good idea :)

Comment: fixed the link. sorry about that. had to change my github username a while back

Comment: How does this stand up to the native memcache driver -> http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/caching.html#memcached

Answer (score 3):

Codeigniter V2.1.0 supports caching
http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/caching.html#memcached

Comment: I assume this is better that the library above?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an introduction to memcached and PHP:

> [enhance_php_session_management](http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net/techblog/article/enhance_php_session_management/)

As far as using memcached from CI, I imagine you would want to either add the caching code directly into your models, or from your Controllers you would want to check the cache before querying data from a model.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function index()
    {
        // manual connection to Mamcache
        $memcache = new Memcache;
        $memcache->connect("localhost",11211);

        $data=$memcache->get("test_key");

        if($data){
            echo 'cache data:';
            var_dump($data);
        }else{
            $data=$this->db->query("SELECT count(*) as ca FROM table WHERE typ=1 ")->row();
            $memcache->set("test_key",$data,false,10); // 10 seconds
            echo 'real data:';
            var_dump($data);
        }

    }
```